# Problem with openmpi and or petsc

Tags: dpkg

I encounter a problem when compiling dealii using petsc/openmpi. I know that this may not be the proper forum
for submitting a bug, but the ReportingBugs page was not helpful. The problem apparently only occurs on Ubuntu 16.04.

One of the people involved with the dealii project wrote:

```
======================= Start of written ==============================
uname -srv 
(4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux):
$ cat test.cc
int main() {}
$ mpicxx -fuse-ld=gold test.cc

/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so: error: undefined reference to 'opal_list_item_t_class'
/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so: error: undefined reference to 'opal_class_initialize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This clearly is a bug in the OpenMPI implementation shipped by Ubuntu 16.04. I think someone should open a bug on the Ubuntu (or Debian?) bug tracker but I lack the time to do so right now...

However, it only appears when using the gold linker. If one disables the gold linker, everything works fine.

$ mpicxx test.cc


======================= End of written ==============================
```

On my system, `uname -srv` is 
`Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016`

What I had loaded for packages was, 2 days ago:

```
sudo apt-get install libpetsc-dev

sudo apt-get install petsc*
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev

sudo apt-get install openmpi*
```

When I also commented out:

```
$ mpicxx -fuse-ld=gold test.cc
```

from the build file it worked.

By the way, the way Ubuntu collect bugs leaves much to be desired. I saw no way to send the appropriate text (above) to the appropriate group. An automatic scan of the packages or anything else would never detect it. It also may well be that the ubuntu packages are not responsible but I have to start somewhere.

The ReportingBugs page says everything not to do, but not what to do. I really hate watching and waiting for the punch line in videos and based on what I read I expected no more and didn't watch.

I found elsewhere to use `ubuntu-bug libpetsc-dev` and `ubuntu-bug libopenmpi-dev`, to initialize a way to enter a bug report, but both come up with a dialog searching, then saying "package not installed", then the terminal hangs. Maybe it's me, but it seems things could be more elegant.

For the record. At least for the preview shown below in the input (this) you tend to ignore some `\n`'s